# Questions concerning upper densities

Tags: combinatorics

Let $D(X) = \limsup_{N \rightarrow \infty} \big( \frac{|A \cap \{1,...,N\}|}{N} \big)$ represent the upper density of set $X$; $FS(X)$ be the set of all finite sums of terms/elements in $X$. Note: $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Are the following true:

1. $\forall A \subset \mathbb{N}: D(A) > 0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists^? t, x_1, ..., x_k: x_i \not= x_j \forall i \not= j, x_i \not= t \forall i, t + FS((x_i)_{i \in \{1,...,k\}}) \subset A$
2. $\forall A \subset \mathbb{N}: D(A) > 0, \exists^? t \in \mathbb{N}, (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{N}: t + FS((x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}) \subset A$
3. $A \subset \mathbb{N}: D(A) > 0 \implies^? \forall F = \{x_1, ..., x_n\} \subset \mathbb{N}: |F| = n < \infty, \exists a, b \in \mathbb{N}: a + bF \subset A$
4. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Define $x \in A$ as "special" $\iff \exists y, z \in \mathbb{N}: \{ x, x+y, x+z, x+y+z \} \subset A$. Let $S = \{x \in A: x$ is special $ \}.$ Is it true that: $D(A) > 0 \implies^? D(S) > 0 $? (Presumably, where $x \not= y \not= z, x \not= z$. Note: $x,y,z \not= 0$ by definition of $\mathbb{N}$.)

---

My thoughts:

1. True. A is A.P.-rich by Szemerédi. Take an arithmetic progression $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1,l]}$  of length $l = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ with starting term $a_1$ and common difference $d$. Take $t=a_1$, $x_n = n d \forall n \in \{1,...,k \}$. Then $B = t + FS((x_i)_{i \in \{1,...,k\}}) \subset A \because \forall b \in B, \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1,\frac{k(k+1)}{2}]: b = a_m$.
2. I think false. I need a good counterexample though.
3. True. Let $N = \max(F) = \max(\{ x_1, ..., x_n \})$, where $x_i$ is defined as in the problem statement. Then by Szemerédi, we have the fact that $A$ is A.P.-rich, meaning that there is an arithmetic progression in it of any length that we desire; so, we can just take the length of the arithmetic progression to be $N$. Note that $F \subseteq \{ 1, ..., N \} = G$. The aforementioned arithmetic progression will have form $a+bG \subset A$. Then $a+bF \subset a+bG \subset A$. QED.
4. I think true. There is a proposition that says that $\forall A \subseteq \mathbb{N}: D(A) > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: D(A \cap (A-n)) > 0$. I am not sure where to go from there though.

Comment: Your three questions are incomprehensible to me. Could you kindly restate them in human language, i.e., using words?

Comment: 1. For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with positive upper density and for any natural number $k$, is it true that there are distinct $t, x_1, ..., x_n$ such that the shift by $t$ of the finite sum set of the sequence of x's is a subset of $A$?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Comment: 2. For any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with positive upper density, is there a $t$ and an infinite(!) sequence $(x_i)$ both in $\mathbb{N}$ such that the shift by $t$ of the finite sum set of that infinite sequence(!) is a subset of $A$?

3. Is it true that if $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with positive upper density, then for any set $F$ of natural numbers of form $\{ x_1, ..., x_n \}$ with a finite number $n$ of elements, there are (guaranteed to be) natural numbers $a, b$ that shift and scale $F$ so that it is in $A$?

Comment: 4. Define "specialness" as stated for an element $x$ of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$; (in other words, $x$ is special if there are a pair of natural numbers, $y, z$, such that every finite sum of these terms forms a subset of $A$, the parent set of $x$). Then does the positive upper density of $A$ guarantee the positive upper density of the set of all special numbers in $A$?

Comment: Any thoughts? (I added some of my own.)

Comment: The first two questions look similar to Hindman's theorem, which says that the coloring version is true. I'm not sure if there are density versions of Hindman's theorem, but it's worth looking into